# Сравнить записи в двух таблицах MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица `patients`, где хранятся паспортные данные пациента и поля id-пациента (уникальный), ФИО пациента и т д.  И ещё есть таблица `priem` где хранятся данные касаемые приёма пациентов, id_пациента (чтобы связывать с таблицей patients чтобы знать какой приём какому пациенту принадлежит) вот вытаскиваю из таблицы patients "карту" всех пациентов , а у некоторых ещё нет истории т.е. приёмов.

А, надо чтобы php покрасил их в красный цвет. Например, если у пациента нет ни одного приёма в таблице `priem`, то он покрасил шрифт в красный.

- Как можно сделать это через PHP?
- Объясните логику пожалуйста или идеи у кого какие?

Буду рад любому предложению.

Пытаюсь делать такой запрос:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN patients.card_id = priem.card_id THEN '0' ELSE '1' END FROM patients, priem
```

Но, как потом на PHP сказать что `card_id` равняется нулю то при выводе покрась его в красный.

А, сейчас пока вывожу всех пациентов так независимо от того есть ли у них приёмы или нет:

```
 <tbody> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM patients ") 
            or die(mysqli_error());         
             ?> 
       <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) { ?>                                 <tr>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["card_id"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["fio"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["adress"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>"><?php echo (" ".$row["phone"]." "); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>">Посмотреть</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="del_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>">Удалить</a> <a href="edit_patient.php?id=<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>" rel = "facebox">Изменить  </a></td>

                                        </tr><?php }; ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Comment: А куда вы его собираетесь выводить? Каким образом? Покажите код, который у вас сейчас выводит нужные вам данные, пока что без красного цвета.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик ,  Stanislav Belichenko. Сейчас в вопросе приведу код который выводит.

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему такие вещи надо делать через `LEFT JOIN`. Например:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.patient_id FROM patient AS t1 LEFT JOIN priem AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.patient_id
```

Приблизительно как-то так.
Если `t2.patient_id` равно `NULL`, значит приёмов у этого пациента нет (или не было).Таким образом Вы получаете простой и надёжный признак, по которому можете определить "наличие приёмов".

Дальше дело за малым. Если `t2.patient_id` равно `NULL` устанавливаете для элемента разметки стиль, который покрасит его в красный цвет.

Comment: Такой запрос вернет 15 записей одного пользователя, если у него было 15 приемов. Думаю лучше так `SELECT t1.*, COUNT(t2.id) as total FROM patient AS t1 LEFT JOIN priem AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.patient_id GROUP BY t2.id`. Там где total=0 применять стиль.

Comment: Хорошо, дорогие друзья. Но вопрос состоит собственно в том что как на PHP вывести это. Т е не как покрасить шрифт а как взять значение из MySQL ? допустим как узнать что значение равнаятеся NULL и вывести это на PHP

Comment: @AlexStassov, ну Вы же в тексте вопроса получаете данные из полей выборки. Что мешает обратиться к полю, проверить его на `NULL` (или ноль, как предложили в первом комментарии) и воспользоваться условным оператором?